# Android MediaCodec unable to decode wma files

Tags: android, media, android-mediacodec, stagefright

I have managed to decode `MP3` files using `MediaCodec`. But failing at decoding `wma`files of `mime type = x/ms-wma`. The code works as expected for MP3 files, and i see `MP3Extractor` is instantiated in `[MediaExtractor]`(http://androidxref.com/4.1.2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MediaExtractor.cpp)

But there's no such class `WMAExtractor` in `libstagefright`,

If this is the problem then how `MediaPlayer` can able to play `wma` files ??

Where am i missing things up, or where the mess up??

Can anyone direct me understand this scenario very well

How can i decode `wma` files ?

**NOTE** when i select a `wma file`, i see in log

> Received message for `kKeyCodecConfig`

The device under test is Samsung GTS9300

Comment: I deleted my answer since I just discovered my phone plays WMA as well. :)  I looked at the ADB output for clues. No dice.

Comment: On my HTC M8, WMA plays fine with MediaPlayer. A casual internet search suggests IHVs may bundle additional codecs with the phones. That doesn't answer your question though.  Sorry. :(

Comment: @selbie, Thanks, and i agree that x/ms-wma is proprietary, and hence Android cannot have it AOSP licensed release (correct me if i am wrong). So Handset vendors bundle their custom/legacy codecs to support it, though

Comment: look at ffmpeg or vlc on android for libs to handle codecs missing from base android.

Comment: @RobertRowntree, I do hope so that vendors have exposed wma codec, so trying to do the stuff without external library as far as possible, I knew if it's impossible with only Android source tree, then next is external libraries such you sugested

Answer (score 1):

For `wma` i.e. `Windows Media Audio`, the container format typically would be `ASF` i.e. Advanced System Format or `AVI` i.e. Audio Video Interleave format. AFAIK, `wma` doesn't have an in-built container specification like `MP3` and hence, is dependent on other container formats like `asf` and `avi`.

Most `asf` files have `wma` audio content and hence, if your device supports `asf` files, you should be able to play them. Most samsung devices do play `asf` and hence, it should work out of the box.

Even though the platform may expose a `wma` `MediaCodec` i.e. codec component, you should have a corresponding `MediaExtractor` and hence, you should check if `asf` or `avi` is supported. My bet would be on `asf`.